# How to expose the weakness of bad code

Tags: c#, sql-injection

Hi I've been repeatedly told not to use *concatenation* in my sql code for fear of an *sql-injection attack*.  However I've tried to *crack* my own code with *No success*.  Is out even possible to *sql-inject* through a *window form*?
Please find the relevant piece of code below:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
  "Data Source=PV10\\LOCALSERVER;Initial Catalog=dbtest;Integrated Security=True");

con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
  "select * from Creds where Username= '" + 
   textBox1.Text + 
  "' and Password='" + 
   textBox2.Text + 
  "'", 
  con);

SqlDataReader dr;
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(dr.Read())
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Imagine a user called `' or 1 = 1; drop table Creds--` for example. What could this strange name do? I give you a tip, you´re string becomes something like `"select * from creds where Username = '' or 1=1; drop table creds--"`. The drop-statement get easily be executed because the conditions *allways* mets. All your data is lost.

Comment: Please post minimal code to reproduce the issue. All that message box stuff is not relevant. I'll do that for you this time

Comment: Not only is it vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks, but you're also exercising poor password security. Passwords should never be stored in plaintext. They should be one way hashed and salted, then you compare hashed forms of the password to determine validity.

Comment: Is this a masterclass on how to do sql-injection?

Comment: Semi-related "I've tried to 'crack' my own code with No success" - This is why you have a testing department that tries to break your code. If a programmer didn't think of a case while writing code it's highly unlikely (s)he will think of it while testing it.

Comment: I forgot my password, how can I bypass it? Seems like professional help on how to crack a system...

Comment: So you cannot find the bug, and you conclude that the bug does not exist?  Suppose I told you that I could not find any mistakes in a document written in Ancient Greek; does that mean that there are no mistakes?  You would be foolish to conclude that *if I don't read Ancient Greek to begin with*. We have no evidence that you have the ability to find bugs to begin with, so the fact that you cannot find any here does not mean they do not exist. It means you don't know how to find bugs yet!  Take this as an opportunity to learn this valuable skill.

Comment: Eric Lipert. Your comment is far from a correct interpretation of my question. I asked for a method to expose the weakness of my code.Not such difficult comments as you do.  Plus I've learned nothing from all you said. Thanks to Dmitry Bychenko he's  pointed out what I was seeking. I can use his remarks to appreciate the weakness in string concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many a great thing can be performed:

**Destruction**: put `*' or 1 = 1; drop table Creds --` into `textBox1.Text` and the query will be

```
 select * from Creds where Username= '*' or 1 = 1;
 drop table Creds -- and Password=''
```

you have *two* queries; the second one drops `creds` table

**Deletion**: put `*' or 1 = 1; delete from Creds --` into `textBox1.Text` and the query will be

```
 select * from Creds where Username= '*' or 1 = 1;
 delete from Creds -- and Password=''
```

you have *two* queries; the second one clears `creds` table

**Espionage**: put `' /*` into `textBox1.Text` and `*/ or '*' = '*` into `textBox2.Text` and the query will be

```
 select * from Creds where Username= ' ' /*  and Password= '*/ or '*' = '*'
```

this query returns all the users with their passwords. Start monitor/sniffer and read the values returned. Do you want some data from other table? Just put 
`' union all select SecretField, TopSecretField from Secrets --` into `textBox2.Text` and you'll get

```
select * from Creds where Username= '' and password = ''
union all
select SecretField, TopSecretField from Secrets --'
```

**Hack**: can you see a record "Big boss", "Top secret password"? It's very time to login with this
      username/password and put 
      `*' or 1 = 1; update Creds set salary = 1000000 /*be modest*/ where userName = 'PoorLittleMe'--` into `textBox1.Text`
      and the query will be

```
  select * from Creds where Username= '*' or 1 = 1;
  update Creds set salary = 1000000 /*be modest*/ where userName = 'PoorLittleMe' -- and Password=''
```

again, you have two queries, and it's quite easy to guess what does the second query do; you may want to buy a ticket to Argentina then.

**Trick**: register youself as `d'Artagnan`; such a name being perfectly right when put into query

```
select * from Creds where Username= 'd'Artagnan' and Password='mypassword'
```

will cause a *syntax error* (and most probably *resourse leakage* - you haven't wraped `IDisposable` - `Connection`, `Command`, `Reader` into `using`)

**Finally**, how it *should have been done*:

```
   // wrap IDisposable into using
   // do not hardcode the connection string
   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(/*read the connection string here*/)) {
     con.Open();

     // Make Sql being readable 
     // You don't want at least Username field to be returned (you have in textBox1.Text)
     string sql = 
       @"select Permissions, --TODO: put right fields here
                Status
           from Creds
          where PasswordHash = @prm_PasswordHash and -- do not store password as plain text
                Username = @prm_UserName"; 

     // wrap IDisposable into using
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) {
       // do not store password as a plain text, but as a hash
       //TODO: AddWithValue is not the best choice; put actual parameters' types here 
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_PasswordHash", ComputeHash(textBox2.Text));
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_UserName", textBox1.Text);

       using (dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
         while (dr.Read()) {
           ...
         }
       } 
     }
   }
```

Comment: Aha, so it is a masterclass! ;-)

Comment: @Stefan: I couldn't help but to write it down after "I've tried to crack ... with No success" ;)