# Good prevention from MYSQL injection?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sql-injection

So I've made a form where you login from a DB. Code should be self explanatory.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string MyConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=xdmemes123";
        MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection);
        MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from life.players where DBname='"  + this.username.Text + "' and DBpass='" + this.password.Text +"' ; ", myConn);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        myConn.Open();
        myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        if (count == 1)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.Security = "Secure";
            Properties.Settings.Default.AdminName = username.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.AdminPass = password.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            MessageBox.Show("Logged in");
            this.Hide();
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.ShowDialog();
        }
        else if (count > 1)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.Security = "Insecure";
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!");
        }
        else
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.Security = "Insecure";
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect!");
            myConn.Close();
        }
}
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong. Error copied to clipboard.");
        Clipboard.SetText(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

But my question is if this is safe from MYSQL Injections? And if not, what can I do to make it safe?

And if possible, write or explain how to write this code. I'm quite new to this coding but really do love it and would like to proceed on my program.

Comment: No this is not safe from SQL injection. Go read up on it and you will see immediately why.

Comment: This is exactly how the SQL-injection vulnerability is implemented!

Comment: `this.username.Text == "0'; delete from SomeTables -- "`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40162863/how-to-expose-the-weakness-of-bad-code/40163704#40163704

Comment: Also your passwords are not hashed, that's not acceptable in this day and age either.

Comment: The code has many bugs. SQL Injection is just one of the problems. A  single `using(var myConn=...)` is enough to create the connection and safely close it when no longer needed. Passwords should *never* be stored and checked like that. Just *don't* try to implement your own security, use .NET's mechanisms. No matter how old they may be, they are far better than this. Connection strins should be loaded from settings *and* encrypted, that's already available in .NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is vulnerable to SQL injection, in fact, it's a perfect example - string concatenation and `SELECT *` would allow an attacker to input eg, a password of `x' OR 1=1;#` and retrieve *all* usernames and unencrypted passwords. Even the unnecessary loop to count for results will cause a noticeable delay that will tell the attacker he has succeded.

The following code isn't vulnerable to injection although it is *NOT* the proper way to authenticate passwords. It is for demonstration purposes only. Note that it  *doesn't* use`SELECT *`, only a `SELECT count(*)`:

```
//Reuse the same command with different connections
void InitializePlayerCmd()
{
    var query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM life.players where DBName=@name and DbPass=@pass";
    var myCmd= new MySqlCommand(query);
    myCmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar,30 );
    myCmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.VarChar,200 );
    _playerCheckCmd=myCmd;
}

//.....
int CheckPlayer(string someUserName, string someAlreadyHashedString)
{
    var connectionString=Properties.Settings.Default.MyConnectionString;
    using(var myConn= new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        _playerCheckCmd.Connection=myConn;
        _playerCheckCmd.Parameters["@name"].Value=someUserName;
        _playerCheckCmd.Parameters["@pass"].Value=someAlreadyHashedString;
        myConn.Open();
        var result=_playerCheckCmd.ExecuteScalar();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Parameters.Add` as inline text allows injection to occur, an example of better SQL is:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection( @"datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=xdmemes123"))
{
    conn.Open();
    var command = new SqlCommand("", conn);
    command.CommandText = "select * from life.players where DBname='@sqlName' and DBpass='@sqlPass";
    command.Parameters.Add("@sqlName", SqlDbType.VarChar ).Value = this.username.Text;         
    command.Parameters.Add("@sqlPass", SqlDbType.VarChar ).Value = this.password.Text;
    using (SqlDataReader myReader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
       while (myReader.Read())
       {
           string value = myReader["COLUMN NAME"].ToString();
       }
    }    
}
```

In addition to the injection issue, you don't hash any of your passwords, I recommend looking into that.

Comment: No, no, no, no! [Never use `AddWithValue`](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: I've been told this would be okay? Only use Add, you say?

Comment: Read the link, I'm not going to reiterate what it says.

Comment: @DavidG `AddWithValue` is enough to prevent SQL Injection. Compared to the many bugs in the original code, this is just a misdemeanor. Notice how this answer *fixes* the unsafe connection handling

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I never mentioned the SQL injection part of this answer, I'm well aware of the fact that it works.

Comment: @NewCallum And you have no idea who downvoted you, and it's pretty rude to call anyone out for it.

Comment: I'm sorry @DavidG I thought with the comment + the downvote at the same time, yeah, my bad.

Comment: I would see how this works, but what would I put in ( @"Connection string"))   ? I tried a few things but said keyword database is not supported.

Comment: Er sorry, I put that for readability, I will edit it to use your connection string

Comment: I tried that, but when I launch i get an error saying "The keyword isnt supported: datasource"?

Also what would ["COLUMN NAME"] stand for?

Comment: I dont know about the error, and that reads information from a column, so put any column name you need, I recommend how to read data from a SQL table for more than one value. My answer was to show you how to stop injection as that's what you asked for! Hope I helped in that regard.